# Unexpected behaviour jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a code which fires on element coming into view and also when the element goes out of view

```
var _2017 = $("#2017").offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() - _2017 > -200) {

        jQuery('[id*="_2017"]').each(function(index) {
            $(this).delay(200 * index).fadeIn(200);
        });

    } else {

        jQuery('[id*="_2017"]').each(function(index) {
            $(this).delay(200 * index).fadeOut(200);
        });


    }
});
```

The problem is that jQuery does not target all divs with the id. This code works fine

```
var _2017 = $("#2017").offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() - _2017 > -200) {

        jQuery('[id*="_2017"]').each(function(index) {
            $(this).delay(200 * index).fadeIn(200);
        });

    } else {

    }
});
```

But when I include the code when the element goes out of view. It does not target all divs.

If anyone can help and explain to me what I am doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: i dont think you have have an id starting with a number

Comment: @ChrisLi HTML4 disallowed that but it works in all browsers so HTML5 says it's OK.

Comment: IDs should be unique if you have multiple divs with the same id, use a class instead otherwise js will only get the first element with that id it finds

Comment: @Pointy didnt know that, thanks

Comment: jQuery('[id*="_2017"]') are you trying to concactinate the _2017 variable? If so, shouldn't it be  jQuery('[id*="' + _2017 + '"]') ?

Comment: It is hard to tell what you are trying to do though, please could you create a [mcve]